# Converting from XML to PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am writing PHP soap client.
I used [wsdlbrowser](http://wsdlbrowser.com) to format the soap request correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ws.iws.iaeste.net/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:fetchOffers>
      <token>
                <token>..your token..</token>
      </token>
      <request>
        <exchangeYear>2015</exchangeYear>
        <fetchType>SHARED</fetchType></request>
    </ns1:fetchOffers>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This would be correctly formatted soap request. Or to be specific, the code beetwen first token tag and last request tag is in the point of interest.
How would I transfer this request to PHP for sending it over SOAP?

THis question is connceted to: [PHP Soap client, Java SOAP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29238570/php-soap-client-java-soap-server)

Comment: Are you using SoapClient (inbuilt in PHP) or writing your own? Also, I'd suggest the wrapper for your inner `<token>` element should be named `<tokens>` to avoid conflicts, otherwise you've got `<element><element>Value</element></element>` (both with same name)

Comment: I am using SoapClient

Comment: If you're using SoapClient then you don't need to format it like that, you use SoapHeaders to set any headers you require, then you pass the data object (fetchOffers) into the SoapClient request to your WSDL endpoint

Comment: I updated question with link with code and more informations about problem. I use SoapClient and tried to send data object or array, but it doesn't work. Only way I made it work is with the XML code written above , it works in wsdlbrowser.com. I would like to make it work from PHP code too.

Comment: SoapClient should do it, if you need some debugging hints, this answer might be helpful to you to compare with the XML you already created with wsdlbrowser (but I do not see any WSDL): http://stackoverflow.com/a/28971320/367456

Comment: and well "it doesn't work" is not a correct problem description for Stackoverflow. Just saying.

Comment: I have putted link to related question, that has more info about why "it doesn't work", i figured maybe it would be stupid to write it all again. Anyways, thanks on  MockSoapClient, looks very usefull I'll give it a shot. :)

Comment: wsdl: http://test.iaeste.net:8080/iws-ws/exchangeWS?wsdl